# Rails 4 Destroy Action For Comments Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

My destroy action for my comments is not working. Here is my link:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Comment', article_comment_path(@article, comment), 
                              method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

Here is my destroy action:

```
def destroy
    @article.comments.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to article_path(@article), notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

The pop-up box does come up and allow me to hit ok. It flashes to say is was successful, but the comment is not deleted. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing us how the `@article` is being populated so let's pretend it's not available and start fresh. First, you need to find the parent `Article`. The ID of the article should be available in the params as `article_id`. Next, you need to use the article's `comments` collection and destroy the comment with ID = `params[:id]`.

```
def destroy
  article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  article.comments.find(params[:id]).destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to article_path(article), notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Technically you don't need to destroy the comment via the `comments` association but it's always a good practice.

Comment: Ahh, this was it. Because I didn't have params[:id] I wasn't finding the specific comment. Thank you both for your help. Just a Rails noob trying to learn the best he can. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are calling destroy on the whole `@article.comments` collection, not on a single comment.

Second, you will need to paste log output for the request/response to be more helpful.  My guess is you are throwing an error.